# How to return json that include rendered view in Grails?

Tags: grails

I want to return json data to generate a graph with javascript in the graph section and show a rendered view with model in the table section. Is it possible to do it in Grails ?

Here is the code,

```
render(contentType: "text/json"){[
       'medias' : mediaList,
       'total' : Total,
       'startTime' : StartTime,
       'endTime' : EndTime,
       'table' : (view: 'ajax/report', model : [activeMenu : 'report', medias : mediaList, total : Total])
]}
```

Thanks

Comment: What renz means below is that you can pass a Map and convert it to JSON: render view: 'something', model: [ ['medias' : mediaList,
       'total' : Total,
       'startTime' : StartTime,...] as JSON, tableData: tableData]

Answer (score 0):

Build your JSON data first in the controller. Then you can return it from your controller like this:

```
model : [graphData:graphData as JSON, tableData: tableData]
```